# Multiple filter clauses for query and subsequent report from unbound form controls, button activated

Tags: ms-access

Been a while since I used Access and now stuck with a reporting problem.

I have a form, with various unbound controls. There a start date, end date and three levels of business/asset/location in combo boxes.

I can get my query and report to work for each of these as individual 'where' clauses when clicking on a button. That's fine.

However I would like to know what code I need to use when clicking a button so I can combine one or more of the above controls to filter the report i.e. my date range + Business, or date + Business + Asset etc.

I have been trawling the internet and testing different variations but seem to have gone through the error book so far.

My latest effort (on click) as one long string gives me a data mismatch error. If I remove the BU/Asset/Facility parts then my date range code does work. However, it's the combination of these I want to filter by.

`DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="rptVerification_Results", View:=acViewPreview, WhereCondition:="[Date Entered] Between #" & Me.StartDate & "# AND #" Me.EndDate & "#""" And "BU = " & Me.cboBusiness & "" And "Asset = " & Me.cboAsset & "" And "Facility = " & Me.cboFacility & ""`

As you can probably tell I'm winging it and need some direction please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can be tricky to get the combination of quoted strings and form fields right, as you need to be aware of which quotes are being used to concatenate the WhereCondition string together and which quotes are being presented to the query engine. You also need to know which fields are text and which are numeric, because text fields need to be enclosed in quotes in the resulting string, while numerics don't. I'm assuming below that cboBusiness, cboAsset and cboFacility are all text.

I suggest you create a separate variable to store your WhereCondition in:

```
Dim myWhereCondition As String
myWhereCondition = "[Date Entered] BETWEEN #" & Me.StartDate & "# AND #" & Me.EndDate
    & "# AND BU = '" & Me.cboBusiness 
    & "' AND Asset = '" & Me.cboAsset 
    & "' AND Facility = '" & Me.cboFacility & "'"
DoCmd.OpenReport ...
WhereCondition:=myWhereCondition
```

You can then create a debug breakpoint on the "DoCmd" statement and check the value of "myWhereCondition" in the Immediate window, to make sure it is formed correctly, before DoCmd runs.

IIRC, you can use apostrophes/single quotes as an alternative to double quotes in MS Access, as I've done above.  If this is not the case, then each of the single quotes above would need to be converted to "double double quotes" (because a double quote on its own would terminate the string).

The somewhat messier "double quotes everywhere" version of the WhereCondition would be:

```
myWhereCondition = "[Date Entered] BETWEEN #" & Me.StartDate & "# AND #" & Me.EndDate
    & "# AND BU = """ & Me.cboBusiness 
    & """ AND Asset = """ & Me.cboAsset 
    & """ AND Facility = """ & Me.cboFacility & """"
```

Note that if any of the cbo fields are numeric, you need to remove the corresponding single (or double double) quotes from each side of that field.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer and explanation. I really appreciate that. I will go and experiment some more using your guidance. Then report back either way. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi - I have been experimenting with this and not had much success. Had to try removing the quotes as I think it was trying to resolve the combos on the numerical (hidden) field. Although the data in the query table shows those combos as the text value. If I enter the dates only and nothing in the combos then I get a data type mismatch error. If I add the combo's as well then it starts to open the report but hangs and has no data.  Is there an easier way to do this multi criteria filter/search from a form?

Comment: If the values returned by your combos are numeric, then, as mentioned, you won't need the additional surrounding quotes.  Did you try the suggestion of creating a separate variable for the WhereCondition and displaying its value at a debug breakpoint in your VBA? It would be useful if you could post that as it should help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Apologies, trying to work this part-time and can't seem to work this annoying comment box either :)  So I had to combine the code like this:  /// Dim myWhereCondition As String
myWhereCondition = "[Date Entered] BETWEEN #" & Me.StartDate & "# AND #" & Me.EndDate & "# AND BU = '" & Me.cboBusiness & "' AND Asset = '" & Me.cboAsset & "' AND Facility = '" & Me.cboFacility & "'"
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="rptVerification_Results_List_ALL, View:= acViewPreview, WhereCondition:=myWhereCondition
WhereCondition:=myWhereCondition

Comment: I would love to write a normal answer in this comment box without accidentally sending it by pressing enter. So it was the messier double quotes version which gave me a data type mismatch. So then had to change to: Dim myWhereCondition As String
myWhereCondition = "[Date Entered] BETWEEN #" & Me.StartDate & "# AND #" & Me.EndDate & "# AND BU = "" & Me.cboBusiness & "' AND Asset = '" & Me.cboAsset 
    & "' AND Facility = '" & Me.cboFacility & "'" DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="rptVerification_Results_List_ALL, View:= acViewPreview, WhereCondition:=myWhereCondition

Comment: That gives me run time error 3075:  Syntax error in string in query expression '[Date Entered] BETWEEN #1/1/2020# AND 11/19/2020# AND BU = "& Me.cboBusiness' AND Asset = " AND Facility = ".

Answer (score 0):

Try this *WhereCondition*:

```vb
Dim WhereCondition As String

' First, adjust the WhereCondition:
WhereCondition = "([Date Entered] Between #" & Format(Me!StartDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Me!EndDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) And BU = '" & Me.cboBusiness & "' And Asset = " & Me.cboAsset & " And Facility = " & Me.cboFacility & ""

' Then, open report:
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="rptVerification_Results", View:=acViewPreview, WhereCondition:=WhereCondition
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, thank your for your reply. When I enter that I am getting an error on the second Format reference. Says "Expected: list separator or )". Is there a piece of syntax missing?

Comment: Yes. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you Gustav. So now for both version above I had to remove the double quotes and change to single as the combos must be resolving as numeric. So in both versions above the report will now open but there is no data. I have tried various combinations of just dates, or dates plus one or more combos and all show no data on the report. Do I have this completely wrong? Should there be some sort of OR statement as well?

Comment: Uh, hard to tell with no data. But reduce the filter until data are returned, then expand the filter step by step.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is the AND. I pulled the where condition back to only BU and Asset and tested. The expression wants all parameters or it returns nothing. I was thought if one was empty then it would ignore and return data for those competed search terms in the relevant fields. How do I adjust that to reflect an AND/OR situation for all of those fields in the filter?  Let's keep it simple on one line for now:  WhereCondition:="BU = '" & Me.cboBusiness & "' And Asset = '" & Me.cboAsset & "'" Or Asset = something?

Comment: The simplest and the recommended method is to check the variables first and, if any of these holds a value for "return any value", then leave that condition out when you build the where condition.